# Resizing Vim Vertical Scroll Bars in Tmux

Tags: macos, vim, macvim, tmux

Currently my vim set up with two vertical sessions/panes looks like this:

[image: vim]

I want to move those vim vertical scroll bars over to the middle of the Tmux pane so the vertical scroll bar & the edge of the tmux pane are identical.  I take it something needs to be in my `.vimrc` to do that but I'm unsure of what.

To answer any of your follow up questions, yes I did draw those arrows myself.

Comment: I'd suggest you take some time getting more comfortable with the basics before going plugin-crazy. *You* are the one whom added `set colorcolumn=XX` to your config, don't you?

Comment: @romainl I don't think OP is the one who set the `cc`. I guess he just copied some settings into his vimrc. or, again, some "vim distribution".. :-)

Comment: Can you tell me more about your setup? It looks great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your screenshot, I am pretty sure it is not "scrollbar"! It should be colorcolumn.

terminal vim has no scroll bars.

if you don't like the color column, you can disable it, by `:set cc=""`

To more detailed information about `colorcolumn`, `:h 'cc'`